# ASMX: Issue to send user credentails from client side to service end

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

i consult these two web site just to know how to work with soap header

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4398/authentication-for-web-services-using-soap-headers

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27365/Authenticate-NET-Web-Service-with-Custom-SOAP-Head

i also develop my web service this way. see the code

```
namespace CustomAuthWithHTTPModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SecureWebService
    /// </summary>
    public class Authentication : SoapHeader
    {
        public string User;
        public string Password;
    }

    public class SecureWebService : WebService
    {
        public Authentication authentication;

        [WebMethod]
        [SoapHeader("authentication", Required = true)]
        public string ValidUser()
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Customer"))
                return "User is in role customer";

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return "User is a valid user";
            return "not authenticated";
        }

    }

}
```

in my console apps i create the proxy of the above web service just by add web reference. the problem is AuthHeaderValue or UserCredentialsValue both property is not being expose at client side by which i can send user credentials. see my client code

```
ServiceReference1.SecureWebServiceSoapClient xx = new ServiceReference1.SecureWebServiceSoapClient();

            ServiceReference1.Authentication a = new ServiceReference1.Authentication();
            a.User = "Hello";
            a.Password = "Hello";
            xx.AuthHeaderValue  or xx.UserCredentialsValue // not being expose
```

guide me where i made the mistake. i am working with VS2013 IDE. thanks